# How to install bathtub

Tags: concrete, basement, floor, bathtub

I want to install a tub on basement bath where drain pipes are already installed and sticking out from concrete floor. I need to know how to raise the level of the tub from the floor in order to have enough space underneath to connect to drain without having to break into concrete. The space from the tub drain opening to the floor is 1/2 inch.
Are  cement board or plywood options to install tub on top of? If so, how do i secure these to concrete floor?

Comment: Concrete is not immutable. The pipes are left sticking up so they don't fill with concrete and so you know where they are when you start chiseling into the concrete. Raising the tub is a lot more work (and increases the odds of falling when exiting the tub) than simply opening the hole needed to put the drain where it belongs.

Comment: Do you have a picture or sketch?  You can cut the pipe on the concrete floor and the tub should sit on the ground.

Comment: I can't add a pic here, but the drain itself is not the problem. The problem is making room for the horizontal branch of the overflow pipe coming on to the down drain.